# Should the called function always check the array size in C?

Tags: c, arrays, coding-style

This is rather a question about programming style than about technicality:
Should my C function always require an argument for the length of an array although the function is not dependent on it?

So either like this `void foo(int* a, int size)` or like `void foo(int* a)`

E.g. when the function just manipulates the first 128 bits of array, should the function require an array length and first of all check if the array is of the right length or should I trust the caller that he follows the documentation and only calls the function with the right size of the array?

I am new to C, so I fear something like an buffer overflow might be possible. A technical reasoning for why one is better than the other would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Not mandatory, but if you do, your function will be more _modular_.

Comment: Never blindly trust programmers to do the thing they should do, so yes; you should always add a length in this kind of functions.

Comment: Take the functions in the C library as good examples. They offer both approaches (like `strcmp`vs. `strncmp`). Generally speaking, the philosophy of C is "If checking the programmer knows what he's doing comes at a cost, assume he is." and "let the programmer decide."

Comment: Does C, like C++, use `size_t`? If so, you should use that for the second parameter as opposed to `int`.

Comment: @JDługosz `size_t` originated in C, as indicated by the fact that in C++, you access it via the C header `<cstddef>`, so yes. I doubt its use is enforced/consistent as much in C libraries as in C++ ones, however. It's a good practice, though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My rule is to differentiate between interface points and internal functions.  Interface functions need to be paranoid and robust, but internal functions can assume that the caller knows what they are doing and can opt for efficiency over robustness.

Answer (score 3):

A general rule should be to make errors known as soon as possible. You can have an error be caught at compile time, link time or run time or never be caught and have undefined behaviour.

Since you can check the size and produce a run time error, I would say that is better then have undefined behaviour if a user of your function passes a smaller array.

Of course sometimes speed is more important and that extra if will not be desired, then you have to relay that your users will read the documentation. That is how a lot of standard library functions are written. But this should be edge cases in your program. In general prefer to catch errors so you have less bugs in your code.

Comment: _"A general rule should be to make errors known as soon as possible."_ — I'm quite surprised to see _this_ in a C thread. Doesn't seem to go very well together with the C design philosophy.

Comment: @tuple_cat At the beginning the question had a C++ tag :)

Comment: @tuple_cat "Doesn't seem to go very well together with the C design philosophy." - I would love to hear why. I didn't know C is specific in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, because you are trying to understand the intent behind the programming style / approach, before using it blindly.

Let me give you my perspective. A code is considered to be healthy, if it conforms to the following.

- If you are able to read & understand the code, without the need of comments.
- If your code is maintanable easily for future maintanence engineer without much difficulty.
- If you are able to add extensions to the original code, without changing the original code drastically
- If your code is closed / unaffected for the modifications in the set of inputs i.e your code solves all different variations of same use-case. Please refer [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

The notion of including the length in the function signature, falls on the first 2 bullet points above.

As an author of a feature / logic, you know exactly what you are going to achieve and hence you don't want to add the length. However, think of case, some time later a bug comes in, and you are not there anymore in the project and someone else is taking over the role of maintenance. It will take considerable amount of effort for the engineer to make sense of what you had written and perform the fix.

While some argue that, they could write comments / have a low level documentation etc, it is not always a viable solution. The proper way is to follow a programming style that makes the code review intuitive and help future developers to contribute to the project at ease.

To sum-up, No, it not mandatory to provide a length, however it is always recommended to follow  good coding guidelines to foster good ecosystem.

If you want to contribute to any of the opensource project, then you should embrace this concept for sure :-)

Good Luck!

Comment: "The notion of including the length in the function signature, falls on the first 2 bullet points above." - vigorously disagree. I note that you didn't explain _why_, just reeled off a bunch of platitudes that don't really say anything. So, why do you think including the size (A) makes people not "able to read & understand the code" and (B) makes the code not maintainable "without much difficulty"?

Comment: Well the purpose of adding the length is to capture certain error scenarios and also to prevent certain error scenarios. By the time, I wanted to answer those, I saw those answered already. So instead of quoting the same point, I just wanted to give other perspective of healthy coding.

Comment: Assume that the author didn't specify the length explicitly and the code inside the function works with magic number 128 / MACRO and assume the caller & callee are part of different component maintained differently. Then for future developer he might be skeptical about the magic number 128. That's where the maintainability part comes into picture.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
Yes, you should. :D
Long answer:
Since your array is actually a memory pointer, you cannot easily get the real size of it. So, if your function should modify the array data, it's wise to check if it can actually do it without overwriting memory that is not allocated to your array.
It's generally a good practice to check memory limits before writing data to a pointer! ;)

Comment: [re deleted comment] indeed, with just a pointer, it's not "cannot easily": you simply cannot know the size of the corresponding allocation. (someone might say you can leverage how your OS tracks this information, but that is, at best, a dangerous hack)

Answer (score 1):

I'll put it ths way, as Souvrav said it's not mandatory, meaning that if you are 100% sure that the length is "right", you can skip the check, however it's not recomended even if you are 120% sure that there won't be an overflow. Also adding this check makes the function usable for cases when you are not sure about the length, so it's better to add it strait away even if you think you do not need it, it may come in handy when and if your code grows.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C, you should "trust the programmer".

There's no way to ensure that the `size` parameter is the actual length of the array. It could be any arbitrary number. So why bother (and clutter the interface) (and slow down the program)?

Comment: I am not disgreeing with you, but some industries like automotive, aerospace & defense insist on C and don't "trust" C++

Comment: C can be safe. You don't have to make it safe if you don't want to, but let's not imply it's inherently un(able to be)safe. A good programmer can make it so. I think C++ is great, but I also think you're extrapolating from your own biases here.

Comment: C can be safe in some context, but in _this specific case_, there's no way to ensure that the "length" parameter is the actual length of the array. It could be any arbitrary number. There's absolutely _no_ way to ensure that an array parameter has a specific length. I don't see how that's not inherently unsafe.

Comment: Right, _in this specific case_. It could be made safe by, e.g., using a `struct` containing a pointer and a size value. Your closing sentence was a lot more general than this, and that's what I was responding to.